# My self-signed certificate is being rejected by the client

Tags: node.js, ssl, self-signed-certificate

On the backend I have a newly created node https + express server, it only have one test endpoint called `/test` which just logs some message. The openssl configuration file(called `req.cnf`) used to create the certificate and the key is:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
CN = www.localhost.com
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = www.localhost.com
DNS.2 = localhost.com
DNS.3 = localhost
```

then I call this command in the same path where the config file is:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout cert.key -out cert.pem -config req.cnf -sha256
```

On the other hand, in the frontend I have Vue calling that `/test` endpoint through a button.

Now in firefox I get this error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
at https://localhost:3001/test. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

And in Chrome:

```
GET https://localhost:3001/test net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Some notes:

- I get the same errors if instead of `localhost` I use the local network ip.
- If I change the node server from `https` to `http` then the request works just fine without errors.
- The server is reading the cert and key files correctly, there is not error on that part.

What can I do to make this self signed certificate to work?

Comment: **You must install the self-signed cert _in the truststore(s) used by the browser(s)_.** Firefox normally uses its own truststore, so install the cert in your Firefox profile, unless your instance of Firefox has been configured to use a system store. MSIE, Edge, and Chrome on Windows all use the Windows store, so install there. Safari and Chrome on MacOS or iOS use those systems' stores, ditto. For other clients, search for other Qs or the rest of the web, or ask a more complete Q. This isn't programming and I'm not sure it's development.

Comment: In the `certificate manager` from firefox I added my certificate in the `your certificates` tab, and also added it to the `authorities` tab but still firefox tells me that "The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed".

Comment: In Firefox "Authorities" is definitely the (only) correct place, but on re-testing (with 102 ESR, after waiting for a convenient time to update) there have been changes since I last used it. First it won't import a cert with the config you posted, saying it's "not a CA cert"; I had to add basicConstraints=CA:true . After that when I test with a manual connection (enter `https://localhost` in the bar) I get the 'security risk' interstitial with an error about "CA cert used for End Entity", but I am allowed to add an exception and then it works. If you are connecting from within code, ...

Comment: ... maybe the interstitial doesn't work and it just fails. But I only get an error about 'self-signed' if I use a cert that is _not_ imported.